# C++ behavior of a default(implicit) copy constructor in a derived class

Tags: c++

I have a question about the behavior of default copy constructor. For example, a class like this:

```
class A{
public:
    A(){}
    A(const A& a){}
    ~A(){}
    void foo(){}
};
class B:public A{
    public:
    B(){}
    B(const B& b){}
    B& operator=(const B& b){return *this;}
    ~B(){}
    virtual void foo(){}
};
class C:public B{
public:
    C(){}
    C& operator=(const C& c){a_=c.a_; return *this;}
    ~C(){}
    void foo(){}
protected:
    A a_;
};
```

if I will create a new object of class C like:

```
C* c1 = new C();
```

the steps would be:

1. creating of A by explicit A()
2. creating of B by explicit B()
3. creating of A by explicit A() (protected member a_ in class C)
4. creating of C by explicit C()

if I will initialize a new object of class C like:

```
    C c2(*c1);
```

it will invoke the default copy construcor of C. As far as I know, the steps would be:

1. calling implicit copy constructor of class C
2. It invokes explicit A(). 
   Why not the A(const A& a)?
3. explicit B(const B& b). 
   Why not by B() like the base class A?
4. Than it will finally  invoke explicit A(const A& a) for protected member in class C a_. 
   What is the difference this time? Why now it is a copy c'tor
5. explicit C& operator=(const C& c) being called. 
   Why does it invoke operator=? As far as I know, copy constructor is used when we initializing a new object and not the assignment operator
6. A(const A& a) being called for a_ = c.a_ (in body of C& operator=)

How the default copy constructor behaves? What rules does it have?

I tried to search the implementation of a default copy constructor on the internet but I didn't find something that explains this behavior. Can anyone suggest something to read about this issue?

Comment: If you added proper base-class initialization to `B(const B& b)`, notably `B(const B& b) : A(b)`, I imagine this would behave as desired, rather than as coded. And I concur with Dave. there is no invoke of `operator =` of *any* flavor in this even as posted (assuming you fixed the access problems in `B` (i.e. everything is `private`) and the missing body of `~B()`.

Comment: I fixed the private to public. But the body of ~B() supposed to be empty. I'm asking about that specific case.

Comment: It wasn't that it wasn't empty; *it wasn't even there*. `~B()` with no semi-colon and no inline body wouldn't compile. Look at your original post. If you're going to implement it, then *implement it*.

Comment: you're right. sorry about that

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9178204/560648?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a derived class copy constructor such as...

```
C(const C& c) {...}
```

You might think this would call A's and B's copy ctors automatically, but it doesn't. The implicit behavior is as if you had written...

```
C(const C& c) : B() {...}
```

... And then B's B() does...

```
B() : A() {...}
```

If you want copy ctors to be called up to your base classes you need to explicitly specify that behavior like so...

```
C(const C& c) : B(c) {...}
```

Implicitly generated copy ctors already do this for you.

As far as your observation that `operator=` is called in your situation, [it isn't](https://ideone.com/vj2I9W). I don't know why you think it is.

Comment: I must disagree, Default copy constructor will call copy constructors from base classes. It was already covered in this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178204/why-does-the-implicit-copy-constructor-calls-the-base-class-copy-constructor-and).

Comment: @gandgandi ya I know I removed that bit before you commented, my bad.

Comment: @Dave maybe he confused it with operator() and even then the operator wouldn't be called.

Comment: I know that `operator=` is called because i put `cout` in its body.

Comment: and the implicit behavior of this code was `A(),  B(B&),  A(A&), C::operator=,A(A&)`

Comment: @gandgandi: `B` does not have a default copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Compile and run, check the comments in the code, it will be more clear:

```
#include <iostream>

class A{
public:
    A()
    {

    }
    A(const A& a)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor FOR A is being called" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual ~A(){}
    void foo(){}
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B()
    {

    }
    B(const B& b)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor FOR B is being called" << std::endl;
    }
    B& operator=(const B& b){return *this;}
    virtual ~B()
    {

    }
    virtual void foo(){}
};

class C : public B
{
public:
    C()
    {

    }

    //if you remove this copy constructor, instead of only C being called, both A and B's copy constructor will be called
    C(const C& c)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor FOR C is being called" << std::endl;
    }

    C& operator()(const C& c)
    {
        std::cout << "Operator is being called" << std::endl;
        a_=c.a_;
        return *this;
    }

    ~C()
    {

    }
    void foo()
    {

    }
protected:
    A a_;
};

int main()
{
    C* c = new C();
    C c2(*c); //copy constructor C will be called since we declared one, otherwise both A's and B's copy constructor would be called
    c2(c2); //here the operator() will be called but not above, changed that one to operator() since operator= didn't make sense
    delete c;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question was about that specific case and about the behavior of default copy constructor in general in different cases. But thanx anyway